# Taint verification of a string

Tags: android, imei, taint

I developed an application that extract the IMEI of the android and stores it in a string.To verify if this string is tainted or not by using eclipse,i used "getTaintString" as following:

```
import dalvik.system.*;
import dalvik.annotation.*;

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String device_id = tm.getDeviceId();

Taint.getTaintString(device_id);
```

but it gives the following error:

Taint cannot be resolved

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To use the dalvik.system.Taint class in your code in Eclipse, you have 
to build TaintDroid with "make sdk" and point Eclipse at the resulting 
SDK. Please search the archives of this mailing list for additional 
details on how to do this.
Source - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/taintdroid/DxUB82vph4U